# Drupal module Azure Blob broken images

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I just started building a Drupal site with Azure.  I installed the [Azure Blob module](https://www.drupal.org/project/azure_blob) and everything works correctly (local environment) including displaying and uploading images to the storage blob.  However, after deploying the site and database to a staging server, all the images are broken.  I made sure the images are present since I've uploaded them while working locally.  I'm unable to locate what the actual issue is.

The module hasn't been updated for a while and I spent some time digging through the code for the module, but without avail.  I was wondering if anyone has run into similar issues and could perhaps point me to the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out what the problem is.  I was unable to display or upload images when everything is deployed to the Azure, unsure of what the exact problem was I went through the process of trial and error by eliminating possible causes one by one.  It all comes down to making a change in the module itself.  In the file "azure_blob.streamwrappers.inc", go to the function createStorageClient.  You need to specify a BlobEndpoint in the configuration.

```
if (!isset(self::$clients[$scheme])) {
  // Obtain user configuration from database
  $configuration = ctools_export_crud_load('azure_blob', $scheme);

  if (isset($configuration)) {
    // @todo Use shared access signature to specify a specific blob endpoint
    $connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=' .
      $configuration->account . ';AccountKey=' . $configuration->primary_key . ';BlobEndpoint=http://[StorageName].blob.core.windows.net/';

    self::$clients[$scheme] = 
      ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connection_string);

    // Store other configuration properties in client object
    self::$clients[$scheme]->blob_container = $configuration->blob_container;
    self::$clients[$scheme]->cache_control = $configuration->cache_control;
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception(t('Invalid storage scheme "@stream"', array('@stream' => $scheme)));
  }
}

return self::$clients[$scheme];
```

I hope this helps whomever that runs into the same issue in the future.  I was literally pulling my hair out trying to find a solution for 2 days :)